# kubernetes ingress and https redirect for apache not working

Tags: apache, kubernetes, gcloud, kubernetes-health-check

if i enable redirect in apache from http to https, the **ingress health rule** wouldn't be able to locate the apache services giving it a "UNHEALTHY" status, this on google cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research this is the best solution i could came up with was adding this in your apache pod

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

where `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp` is the location for your app
remember if u redirect everything, the **ingress health rule** would get redirected everytime and marking it as "UNHEALTHY", thats why u need to tell apache what to redirect only.